# How can I build hsdis-amd64.dll for openJDK11?

Tags: java, jit

I'm doing a course on Java Performance Optimization and I'm stuck trying to download all the required files so that I can build this DLL hsdis-amd64.dll. It's supposed to allow me to use JITWatch and learn about the JIT during this course.

Anyway, the instructions [here](https://dropzone.nfshost.com/hsdis/) say to download hotspot for your exact JDK.
My JDK is 11 build 11+28.

This is the [openJDK repository](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/) where

1. I'm supposed to look underopenJDK/MYVERSION/hotspot
2. Click tags, select my exact release
3. Click bz2 to download
4. After which I'm supposed to patch the hotspot hsdiss library I just downloaded and then
5. re MAKE it.
6. Throws the output DLL into my java/bin/

I see the DLLs can't be prebuilt because of licence issues. Any  idea how people are using JITWatch with openJDK11?

Answer (score 0):

I have built it recently based on a post from here: https://dropzone.nfshost.com/hsdis/

1. Install Cygwin. At the Select Packages screen, add the following packages (expand the All/Devel category, Search for the package’s name, and change the package’s New status from Skip to the latest non-Test version):

   gcc-core
   make
   mingw64-i686-gcc-core (only needed for hsdis-i386.dll)
   mingw64-x86_64-gcc-core (only needed for hsdis-amd64.dll)
2. Run Cygwin in a terminal shell
3. Download GNU binutils 2.32 to your Cygwin home directory, and extract it with tar xvf binutils-2.32.tar.xz in a place that you can easily access from cygwin paths.
4. Change to the JDK/src/utils/hsdis directory
5. Build 64bit Windows like this:

   make OS=Linux MINGW=x86_64-w64-mingw32 BINUTILS=/cygdrive/c/cygwin/binutils-2.32
6. If the above command fails (as it might with some unpatched JDK builds) with:

   compress.c:(.text+0x5b): undefined reference to `inflateInit_'

Edit the Makefile, look for libiberty.a and change the library list to include libz.a, like this:

```
   LIBRARIES =  $(TARGET_DIR)/bfd/libbfd.a \
        $(TARGET_DIR)/opcodes/libopcodes.a \
        $(TARGET_DIR)/libiberty/libiberty.a \
        $(TARGET_DIR)/zlib/libz.a
```

Comment: Genius. Thanks for writing this answer. I will try it asap and get back to this thread!